# Variable getting stuck, won't change

Tags: jquery

So I have a list of elements like:

```
<span class="rank" id="someID1" user_id="1">Whatever 1</span>
<span class="rank" id="someID2" user_id="2">Whatever 2</span>
<span class="rank" id="someID3" user_id="3">Whatever 3</span>
```

And I have a JQuery Selector set up like:

```
$(".rank").click(function(){
    var url = "utilities.php?id=" + $(this).attr("user_id");
    $(".rank").editable("save_url", {
        loadurl: url, type: "select" });
});
```

Now, the issue is that no matter which one I click, the "user_id" is always whatever the first one I click is.  It's very frustrating and I don't understand why it's sticking.  If If use console.log to check the URL, the id is set properly, but then in the Ajax call it's the first one that I clicked for every one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when the `.editable()` is applied, it's going off the url that was defined immediately before it, which is the url you've built from the first span. You should be building the url from inside the editable call, so that you're always retrieving the user_id attribute of the element that was clicked on.

```
$(".rank").editable("save_url", {
    loadurl: "utilities.php?id=" + $(this).attr("user_id");
    type: "select"
});
```

Comment: Tried that as well, same issue.  Edit:  Sorry, not same issue, I get undefined for it.

Comment: I also don't understand why building the url off of the element would be any different from building it within the editable call.  It still retrieves the user_id of the element clicked.  It actually does it better (because it works), it just ignores it when I pass the URL to editable.

Comment: Well, you do have 3 different 'rank' spans. you define url ONCE, then apply it to all 3 spans at the same time. Internally jquery is running a loop to do your .editable query, but since url is defined outside the loop, it's an invariant inside the loop. Thinking about this some more, my answer wouldn't work either as the $(this) stuff is called ONCE before doing the .editable stuff, so it'll be invariant inside this .editable function call as well. You might have to bite the bullet and do you your own loop over the spans.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to be able to avoid. =/  I have a lot of code like this and I was hoping for an easy answer.  Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".rank").bind("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        url = "utilities.php?id=" + $this.attr("user_id");
    $this.editable("save_url", { loadurl: url, type: "select" });
});
```

Or this:

```
var $rank = $(".rank");

$rank.bind("click", function(){
    var url = "utilities.php?id=" + $(this).attr("user_id");
    $rank.editable("save_url", { loadurl: url, type: "select" });
});
```